# How to ungroup elements in Snap SVG

Tags: svg, transform, snap.svg

I am using Snap SVG to build an editor.
I have a group tag with some transform. 
I want to ungroup the group. I tried adding the elements in the group to parent with a for loop, but the transforms are not working as expected in the ungrouped elements.

Can anybody tell me a way to ungroup elements?

Please find the JS Bin here.

https://jsbin.com/jinita/edit?js,output

Here when I drag the black rectangle, the entire group also moves.
When I drop it, I try to ungroup it, but the transforms are not applying for the group.

PS: I can't call drag() on the group element

Comment: You will need to append the element to the parent (or other) as you mention, but you will need to figure the transform to place on it. If you can provide a minimal example on a jsfiddle with example transform in place, I'm sure we can help further.

Comment: I tried adding a fiddle, but not working: https://jsfiddle.net/harikk09/4p2jvs45/1/

Comment: You would need to include jquery, plus I'm not sure it will allow remote downloads on jsfiddle. You could try a jsbin or something, see if thats better, and include jquery if you use it (something that simple, I'm not sure you need it).

Comment: File not found for the logo.

Comment: logo file is updated. http://182.72.159.116/phppay/logo.svg

Comment: One of the problems here, is that you can't apply transforms to an svg, you would need to do it to a g element. So maybe the best bet is the place the svg inside a g element, and put the transforms on that.

Comment: Both the rectangle and g are inside svg. While start dragging I add  the group into  another group (to mimic the actual scenerio). Then in drag handler I update the coordinates for rect and apply transform for new g. It works as expected. But when I stop dragging, I remove the elements from the new group and add to the svg. That time the issue happens. The transforms are not properly applying.

Comment: I don't want to apply transforms to svg but for the g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a bit confusing, as it looks like you are trying to add a group to itself, but I may be misunderstanding it. I have amended it slightly and selected the group by ID, just to know its the correct one, rather than css selectors.

[jsfiddle](https://jsbin.com/sosirekule/1/edit?html,js,output)

The key part I amended for the transforms is this line...

```
item.transform( g.transform().localMatrix.toTransformString() )
```

Edit: In this case, you can probably shorten it further to

```
item.transform( g.transform() )
```

This makes sure that we are getting the group transform at time of removing from the group, and convert it using toTransformString() (I'm not sure thats entirely necessarily, but often seems to eliminate oddities).

Edit: After the question has been amended slightly, it may be that you actually want the full matrix applying in which case it would be ...

```
item.transform( item.transform().globalMatrix.toTransformString() )
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/voqaxosune/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I dont have to remove the existing group (I remove only the newly created group). I updated the JSBin by adding the text tags into the newly created group for making it much more clear. I am doing some multi selection group movement. that is why I am adding the elements into the group and dragging the new group. https://jsbin.com/jinita/edit?js,output

Comment: Now you can see that the group is moving but the moment I ungroup it, the transforms are getting messed up. this was the actual issue. sorry for the confusion. could you please help me with that?

Comment: I've added a bit, do you mean like that ? There's a bug with your rect dragging code, but I assume you are just focusing on the other bit.

Comment: Actually you are modifying the actual svg structure by removing the group which was already in svg. I dont want to do that. That's why I am creating a g and then remove the newly created g.

Comment: Using your jsbin (not mine), just put this line in your code as mentioned... item.transform().globalMatrix.toTransformString() instead of g.transform().localMatrix.toTransformString()  you will see thats all that matters in the change

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience